# How to check if an variable of any type is an array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-protocols

I tried to cast a swift protocol array as any array, but failed.

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class{
}

class SomeClass: NSObject, SomeProtocol{
}

let protocolArray: [SomeProtocol] = [SomeClass()]
let value: Any? = protocolArray

if let _ = value as? [SomeProtocol]{
     print("type check successed")      //could enter this line
}
```

Above code could work as expected.
However, my problem is, I have a lot of protocols, and I don't want to check them one by one. It is not friendly to add new protocol.

Is there any convenience way to do check if above "value" is a kind of array like below?

```
if let _ = value as? [Any]{
    print("type check successed")    //never enter here
}
```

**edit:**

Inspired by Rohit Parsana's answer, below code could work:

```
if let arrayType = value?.dynamicType{
    let typeStr = "\(arrayType)"
    if typeStr.contains("Array"){
         print(typeStr)
    }
}
```

But these code seems not safe enough, for example, you can declare a class named "abcArray".

Although we could use regular expression to check if "typeStr" matches "Array<*>", it seems too tricky.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
if value != nil {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: value!)
    let isArray = (mirror.displayStyle == .Collection)
    if isArray {
        print("type check succeeded")
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of value using 'dynamicType', here is the sample code...

```
if "__NSCFArray" == "\(page.dynamicType)" || "__NSArrayM" == "\(page.dynamicType)"
    {
        print("This is array")
    }
    else
    {
        print("This is not array")
    }
```

Comment: I am afraid it does not work. "__NSCFArray", "__NSArrayM" seems like an objc array, and I am using swift here. The dynamic type of "value" is actually "Array<SomeProtocol>"