# Use Swift `is` to check type of generic type

Tags: swift, generics

Lets say that I have a variable of type `Any`, and I would like to know wether this is an array or not, here is what I would like to do:

```
if myVariable is Array { /* Do what I want */ }
```

But Swift requires to give the generic type of the array such as :

```
if myVariable is Array<Int> { }
```

But I don't want to check the generic type, I just want to know wether this is an array or not, I tried :

```
if myVariable is Array<Any> { }
```

Hoping that it would match every type of array, but that doesn't work either... (it doesn't match arrays of all types, so if my variable is an Int array, this code doesn't get called for instance)

What should I do ?

Thank you.

**Edit with example of an approach solution that doesn't seem to work:**

```
struct Foo<T> {}

struct Bar {
    var property = Foo<String>()
}

var test = Bar()

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: test)

// This code is trying to count the number of properties of type Foo
var inputCount = 0
for child in mirror.children {
    print(String(describing: type(of: child))) // Prints "(Optional<String>, Any)"
    if String(describing: type(of: child)) == "Foo" {
        inputCount += 1 // Never called
    }
}

print(inputCount) // "0"
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443846/how-to-check-if-an-variable-of-any-type-is-an-array

Comment: @MartinR Actually when I was speaking about Arrays, that was just an example, my problem is much more general as it applies to all other generic types as well.

Comment: @MartinR In fact, I want to count how many properties of a certain generic type a certain class/protocol has, therefore I am using reflection to do that, but then I got stuck when I couldn't find a way to check the type since the type I want to check is a generic one... 

Comment: Just brainstorming here.  It is probably ill advised, but you could look at `String(describing: type(of: v))` and see if it has the prefix `"Array"` or of whatever type you thought it might be.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you! I'm going to try this, it could indeed be broken in future Swift versions but I hope that there will be advancements in the reflection by then...

Comment: @vacawama I also imagine that there could be a problem in case a subclass of the class I want to test is present, in that case the string wouldn't be the same anymore. But here I can put my class as final...

Comment: @vacawama I tested it and it doesn't work, the type doesn't correspond to mine.

Comment: Hmmm. How is your type constructed?

Comment: @vacawama Here the type I want to check is of type FKInput<String>

Comment: @vacawama But with the method you proposed, the type string is :" (Optional<String>, Any)" which doesn't let me know if this is something of type FKInput or not.

Comment: Can you add a self contained, verifiable example to your question?

Comment: @vacawama I edited my question to show it to you 

Comment: `child` is a tuple with 2 values.  You need to look at the second value in the tuple: `if String(describing: type(of: child.1)).hasPrefix("Foo<")`

Comment: @vacawama Wow ! It works thank you !

Comment: I think it would be better to ask yourself why you think you need to do this. The entire notion is fishy.

Comment: @matt I am building a graph and I want the graph to know the inputs of each of its nodes without explicit input registration (an input of a node just needs to be of generic type Input<T>)

Comment: @matt I want those inputs to be simple properties to keep my framework simple to use... if I was to use arrays to store my inputs I would loose the convenience of the Swift strong type system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's 2 things that might work for you.

**Option 1:**

Note that `child` is a tuple containing a `String?` with the name of the property (`"property"` in your example) and the item.  So you need to look at `child.1`.

In this case, you should be checking:

```
if String(describing: type(of: child.1)).hasPrefix("Foo<")
```

---

**Option 2:**

If you create a protocol `FooProtocol` that is implemented by `Foo<T>`, you could check if `child.1 is FooProtocol`:

```
protocol FooProtocol { }

struct Foo<T>: FooProtocol {}

struct Bar {
    var property = Foo<String>()
}

var test = Bar()

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: test)

// This code is trying to count the number of properties of type Foo
var inputCount = 0
for child in mirror.children {
    if child.1 is FooProtocol {
        inputCount += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: #1 will only work for structs, not subclasses of a generic class where the subclass has a different name (like `class Cars : SomeCollectionClass<Car>` since the type is 'Cars' which doesn't start with 'SomeCollectionClass'), and additionally, it also doesn't protect against something else having a similar name, and for #2, there's no way to guarantee that protocol is only applied to that generic type.

Comment: I can't believe there isn't some way to check if something is an array directly.  Adding the extra protocol is introducing a new 'Type' where you already have a type... array!  I've seen this easily solved in languages like C# so I'm hoping they can add something here.  Again, the above work, but they aren't infallible.

Comment: Swift sorely lacks in oriented object concepts (no abstract, no protected, no wildcard in generics, no subclass check with generics, poor reflection..). Duplicating my model classes from my C++ server to Java Android app was quite easy, but with Swift , it's a nightmare every time I have a little complex model architecture..

Answer (score 7):

This is how to test a generic type parameter for conformance:

```
let conforms = T.self is MyProtocol.Type
```

See this post: [Swift: check if generic type conforms to protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124684/swift-check-if-generic-type-conforms-to-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

In Java you would want to use `Array<?>`, in Swift it's not possible, but you can emulate it.

1. Create a protocol `protocol AnyArray {}`
2. Now let all arrays implement this protocol: `extension Array: AnyArray {}`
3. Now you can easily do what you intended to do:

   ```
   if myVariable is AnyArray { ... }
   ```